# Android notification text overlapping

Tags: android, notifications

[image]

On a Huawei phone, the notification bar displays overlapping text, I don't know if this is a android system bug，or my code bug.

```
        NotificationManagerCompat notifyMgr = NotificationManagerCompat.from(appContext);
    if (conversation.hasMessages()) {
        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(appContext,
                AppConstants.NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_CHAT_MESSAGES)
                .setGroup(AppConstants.NOTIFICATION_GROUP_CHAT_MESSAGES)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.app_logo_notification)
                .setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(appContext, R.color.color_main_blue4))
                .setCategory(NotificationCompat.CATEGORY_MESSAGE)
                .setStyle(conversation.buildMessagingStyle(me, isGroup, reason, uuid))
                .setContentIntent(getContentPendingIntent(appContext, conversation))
                .setDeleteIntent(getDeletePendingIntent(appContext, conversation))
                .setVisibility(NotificationCompat.VISIBILITY_PRIVATE)
                .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
                .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
                .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
                .setAutoCancel(true);
      
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
            String messagesStr = appContext.getResources().getQuantityString(
                    R.plurals.chat_notification_conversation_summary,
                    conversation.getTotalMessagesCount(), conversation.getTotalMessagesCount());
            builder.setSubText(messagesStr);
        }
```

//        if (!isGroup) {
//            notificationBuilder.setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(appContext.getResources(), XXxx);
//        }
notifyMgr.notify(conversation.getNotificationId(), builder.build());

Comment: Please add the layout file related to it too.

Comment: only set the style,no setCustomContentView